# run another power shell script in elevated mode as administrator

Tags: powershell, uac, powershell-remoting

I am currently logged into my system as administrator, and run power1.ps1 code to call another power2.ps1 script in elevated mode.

> $command = "C:\script\Power2.ps1"
>
> Invoke-Expression $command

`power2.ps1` includes the block to run the script with admin privileges, but my problem is I that I get a UAC pop-up dialog asking for confirmation where I have to click on Yes.

Code in Power2.ps1

```
If (-NOT ([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal][Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole] "Administrator"))

{   
$arguments = "& '" + $myinvocation.mycommand.definition + "'"
Start-Process powershell -Verb runAs -ArgumentList $arguments
Break
}

Write-Host "Admin Privilege Code Here"
```

Is there any way I can completely automate the process? I will not be able to change the UAC access to disable.

Comment: you could create a scheduled task runs your script and set the privileged account to run this task.

Comment: These scripts are part of the suite ,and gets initiated based on user input. i will not be able to create a scheduled task in that environment.

Answer (score 2):

**Trying to simulate a user's response to a [UAC (User Account Control)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Account_Control) dialog *shouldn't* be done** - because it defeats the entire purpose of UAC - and  ***cannot* be done** (if it could be done, that would be a serious *bug* exploitable by malware and is certainly not something to rely upon; similarly, **while it is possible to *disable* UAC altogether** (which itself requires administrative privileges), **doing so is *strongly discouraged*** for security reasons).

**With UAC in effect:**

- The **only *secure* way to *avoid* a UAC dialog in *direct* invocation is if *the calling process itself* is already running with elevation** (e.g. if it was started with the `Run as administrator` shortcut-menu command). Obviously that just shifts the point in time when a UAC dialog must be answerd.
- There are two ***insecure* alternatives**, both of which **only work *if the calling user is an administrator in principle***:

  - A **convenient, but *ill-advised* option** is to **modify the UAC settings** to not require a UAC prompt when an *administrator* requests elevation, i.e. to *automatically grant the request* - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77412370/45375) for details. This is ill-advised, because any malicious code that manages to run in a non-elevated administrator session can then quietly execute elevated operations.
  - A ***less* insecure option** is to **use a *scheduled task*** to bypass UAC *for a given command* and **allow calling that task *on demand***, as detailed below. This is less insecure in that it limits what a malicious code can do to the specific operation defined in the task.

---

**Using a run-on-demand aux. scheduled task:**

- Create an **auxiliary *scheduled task*** that invokes your `Power2.ps1` script and is configured to run *elevated*.

  - In the Task Scheduler (`taskschd.msc`) UI that means: `Run with highest privilege` must be checked (tab `General`) and also `Allow task to be run on demand` (tab `Settings`).
  - The **task must be configured to run in the same user account that it will be on-demand invoked from**, and that user account **must be a member of the `Administrators` group**.

    - Note that configuring the task to run for *any member* of the `Administrators` group is *not* an option, because that prevents non-elevated on-demand invocation.
  - Be sure to limit the task to a *specific operation*, to minimize the exposure.
- **Use [`Start-ScheduledTask <task-path>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/scheduledtasks/start-scheduledtask) (or `schtasks.exe /Run /TN <task-path>`) to invoke this task *on demand***, from the *same* account that the task is configured for, as noted.

  - `Start-ScheduledTask` (as well as `schtasks.exe /Run`) **runs *asynchronously***, so for synchronous invocation more work is needed - see [this article](https://mcpmag.com/articles/2017/02/09/force-powershell-to-wait-for-scheduled-tasks.aspx).

    - Note that using `-AsJob` to return a job whose completion can be waited for with `Wait-Job` unfortunately appears *not* to help (as of Windows PowerShell 5.1 / PowerShell 7.2.1): the job is reported as completed *before* the task's command has terminated.
  - Also, the task's command invariably runs **in a *new console window*** (if the executable invoked is a console application).

Comment: i have converted my script to exe and from exe file properties i changed it to run as admin. and i call this exe from another auto it script. which has the command #requireadmin will help to run my exe as elevated previllage.