# How to get rid of Windows Installer and Permission request pop ups when running a PowerShell script?

Tags: windows, powershell

This is a very simple part of my script. I'm running a few .msi and .exe files to install the products. However, I need to either click OK for a "Windows Installer" or Yes when permission is needed. Is there a way the script simply does not show these windows, but chooses OK and Yes for anything asked in the background?

You can see I tried /i /quiet /silent /passive but none of these helps.

```
$softwarePath = "mypath"

# Install ODBC 17 and ODBC 18
Start-Process “$softwarePath\msodbcsql17.msi” -ArgumentList “/i /quiet /install /passive” -Wait 
echo "ODBC17 installed"
Start-Process “$softwarePath\msodbcsql18.msi” -ArgumentList “/silent /install” -Wait 
echo "ODBC18 installed"
# Install Web Deploy v3.6
Start-Process “$softwarePath\WebDeploy_amd64_en-US.msi” -ArgumentList “/silent /install” -Wait 
echo "WebDeploy installed"
# Install ASP.NET Core 7.0 Runtime (v7.0.5)
Start-Process “$softwarePath\dotnet-hosting-7.0.5-win.exe” -ArgumentList “/quiet /install /passive” -Wait
echo "dotnet-hosting-7.0.5 installed"
# Install .NET 6.0 Desktop RUntime (v6.0.19)
Start-Process “$softwarePath\windowsdesktop-runtime-6.0.19-win-x64.exe” -ArgumentList “/silent /install” -Wait
echo "windowsdesktop-runtime-6.0.19 installed"
```

[image: Windows Installer]

[image: permission required]

Comment: I use to do that this way: `Start-Process C:\Windows\system32\msiexec.exe -ArgumentList "/i <msiPath> /quiet" -Wait`.

Comment: The dialog in the first screenshot usually pops up when there is a _syntax error_ in a given call.

Comment: The other screenshots show a UAC dialog, which normally cannot be silenced: The only way to avoid [UAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Account_Control) prompts is to either run in an elevated process to begin with or to disable (parts of) UAC altogether, _which is strongly discouraged_.
See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50555081/45375) for background information.

Comment: As aside, don't use curly so-called 'smartquotes' in code, but straight ones instead