# How to clear Windows 10 Clipboard history via VBA and PowerShell command

Tags: vba, powershell, windows-10, clipboard

I want to clear **Windows Operating System Clipboard history** via **VBA** and **PowerShell** command.

I am a **Windows 10** user.

This is the PowerShell command line which clears **Windows Operating System Clipboard history**.

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Restart-Service -Name "cbdhsvc*" -force
```

The following link might be helpful in order to understand what I am talking about.

[https://mspoweruser.com/clear-clipboard-windows/#:~:text=Press%20Windows%20%2B%20I%20on%20your,menu%20of%20the%20Settings%20app](https://mspoweruser.com/clear-clipboard-windows/#:%7E:text=Press%20Windows%20%2B%20I%20on%20your,menu%20of%20the%20Settings%20app).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Clear Office Clipboard with VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32736915/how-to-clear-office-clipboard-with-vba)

Comment: @braX The link you sent is regarding **Microsoft Office Word Clipboard**. My question is regarding **Windows 10 Operating System Clipboard**.

Comment: https://www.automateexcel.com/vba/clear-clipboard/

Comment: @brax I have already tried that code but that code doesnt work for me.

Comment: Could you say more about "doesn't work"? In what way does it  not work? Is there an error message?

Comment: @lit There was no error message. The code was working but the result is nothing.

Comment: @braX, [your second link](https://www.automateexcel.com/vba/clear-clipboard/)  shows how to clear the _current_ clipboard data, but the question is about clearing the clipboard _history_ (a W10+ feature that keeps the last 25 clipboard entries). I've updated the formatting of the question to make that clearer.

Comment: @mklement0 What is the difference between  clearing the current clipboard data and clearing the clipboard history ?

Comment: @DannyColeiro: Clearing the current clipboard data means clearing the clipboard itself, so that attempts to paste from it (e.g. via Ctrl+V) fail. The clipboard _history_ is a separate feature that remembers up to 25 of the most recent entries (the current entry being the first), and requires a different mechanism to access the older entries (e.g. WinKey+V, plus selection of the desired entry). Additionally, you can _pin_ entries to remember them persistently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Prerequisite**:

- You must be running on ***at least Windows 10*** or at least Windows Server 2016 *with the Desktop Experience option installed*, as only then is the clipboard-history feature available.

---

There are **two ways** to **clear the clipboard *history* using PowerShell**:

- **Note**:

  - Both methods by design do *not* clear *pinned* items from the history, i.e. items the current user has explicitly chosen to remember indefinitely.
  - If your intent is **to merely clear the clipboard, i.e. remove its *current* content** (as available for regular pasting), use
    `Set-Clipboard $null`, though note that in PowerShell 7+ this technically doesn't *clear* the clipboard, but replaces the current content with an *empty string*. If that is a concern, use
    `Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms; [System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard]::Clear()`
    Note that clearing the clipboard does *not* remove the previous content from the clipboard *history*.
- **Option 1**: Using the static `::ClearHistory()` method of the **[`Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer.Clipboard`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.datatransfer.clipboard) class**.

  ```bash
  # Windows PowerShell only (not PowerShell 7+)
  [Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer.Clipboard, Windows, ContentType = WindowsRuntime]::ClearHistory()
  ```

  - This **has the advantage of *not* requiring *elevation*** (Run as Administrator).
  - However, because it is a [UWP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Windows_Platform) class, it **works in *Windows PowerShell only***, because [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) at least as of the .NET 8 version underlying the current version, 7.4.x, does not have access to such classes.
  - Also, this **works only from the foreground runspace (UI thread)** and can therefore *not* be used from background [jobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Jobs) (including [*thread*-based](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/threadjob/start-threadjob) jobs), for instance.
- **Option 2**: Using the **[`Restart-Service`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/restart-service) cmdlet** to stop and restart the clipboard history Windows service:

  ```bash
  #requires -RunAsAdministrator
  Set-Clipboard $null; Restart-Service cbdhsvc_*
  ```

  - Unfortunately, this method **only works from an *elevated* PowerShell session**.
  - However, it **also works in PowerShell 7+** and **can also be used in (elevated) non-foreground calls**, such as from jobs.
  - The **`Set-Clipboard $null` call ensures that the *current* clipboard data is removed too** (something that the .NET API call above does automatically), though note that in PowerShell 7+ - unlike in *Windows PowerShell* - this doesn't *clear* the current clipboard, but replaces its content with an *empty string*, which is recorded as such in the history; however, due to restarting the service and thereby clearing the history *after* this call, that won't matter.
  - If you're running on an *older* system (prior to Window 10 or possibly a very early, long-obsolete build of Windows 10), the [wildcard expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Wildcards) will not match an existing service name and the operation will be a *quiet no-op*.

    - To rule out this case, you can run the following:

      ```bash
      if (-not (Get-Service cbdhsvc_*)) { throw "Clipboard history service not found." }
      ```
  - A wildcard pattern is needed, because the clipboard history *service's full name changes on every login* due to a (pseudo) random suffix composed of `_` followed by 5 hex digits, e.g. `cbdhsvc_5e5a8`.

    - It does so, because it is a *per-user service*, as explained in [this SuperUser answer](https://superuser.com/a/1597740/139307).
      Curiously, however, stopping and restarting such services *still requires elevation*.

---

##### Invoke the clipboard history-clearing PowerShell command *from VBA*:

- Use the [`.Run()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/windows-scripting/d5fk67ky(v=vs.84)) method of the `WScript.Shell` COM object...
- ... to invoke [`powershell.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe), the Windows PowerShell CLI, with the `::ClearHistory()` call shown at the top.

  - **Note**: The UI-thread stipulation therefore applies here too: the call must be made from the UI thread of the application that hosts VBA.

The code below runs the PowerShell console window that is invariably created *hidden*, by using `vbHide` window style in the `.Run()` call.
For troubleshooting, switch to `vbNormalFocus`, and place `-NoExit` before `-Command` in the `powershell.exe` call.

```vb
Dim exitCode as Integer

' Run the PowerShell command hidden (vbHide), synchronously (True)
' and obtain its exit code.
exitCode = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run( _
 "powershell.exe -NoProfile -Command [Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer.Clipboard, Windows, ContentType = WindowsRuntime]::ClearHistory()", _
 vbHide, _
 True _
)

If exitCode = 0 Then ' Command succeeded.
    ' Report success.
    MsgBox "Successfully cleared the clipboard history.", vbInformation
Else ' Command indicated failure.
    MsgBox "An unexpected error occurred while trying to clear the clipboard history", vbExclamation
End If
```

---

If, for some reason, the `powershell.exe` call can *not* be made from the UI thread of the VBA-hosting application, you'll need to use the **`Restart-Service` method**, and doing so then **invariably *requires elevation***.

- You must then invoke `powershell.exe` in a *nested* manner so that an inner `powershell.exe` call can *request elevation* via [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process) `-Verb RunAs`.

  - **Important**: Unless the application hosting VBA happens to be running with elevation itself, **you'll get a [UAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Account_Control) dialog to confirm or authorize the elevation request**.

    - As in direct use of PowerShell, the implication is that a *non-admin user* cannot run the command unless an administrator is present to supply their credentials in order to authorize the request.
    - **By security-minded design, you cannot *automate* responding to UAC dialogs, and the only way to *avoid* them from a non-elevated process is to disable (parts of) UAC altogether, *which is strongly discouraged* for security reasons**, or - but only if you are member of the Administrators group in principle - to define a scheduled task that performs the desired operation. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50555081/45375) for details.
  - The code below runs the PowerShell console windows that are created *hidden*, by using `vbHide` instead of `vbNormalFocus` in the `.Run()` call, and by using `-WindowStyle Hidden` in the nested PowerShell `Start-Process` call.
    For troubleshooting, switch to `vbNormalFocus` and use `-NoExit` in both `powershell.exe` calls.

```vb
Dim exitCode as Integer

' Run the PowerShell command with elevation, synchronously, 
' and obtain the exit code.
exitCode = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run("powershell.exe Start-Process -Wait -Verb RunAs -WindowStyle Hidden powershell.exe 'Restart-Service cbdhsvc_*'", vbHide, True)

If exitCode = 0 Then ' Command succeeded.
    ' Display the output.
    MsgBox "Successfully cleared the clipboard history.", vbInformation
Else ' Command indicated failure.
    MsgBox "An unexpected error occurred while trying to clear the clipboard history", vbExclamation
End If
```

Comment: Hi, **mklement0**. Thanks for the answer. I am not familiar with **PowerShell**. So I dont know how to use that code integrated with **VBA**. So please show me whole **VBA** code which contains **PowerShell** command.

Comment: Thank you.  How do I automaticaly press yes on this prompt?  https://prnt.sc/IgjV8vDuAl05      The following link might be helpful: https://superuser.com/questions/1779617/answer-yes-on-powershell-opening-prompt

Comment: @DannyColeiro, by security-minded design, you cannot _automate_ responding to UAC dialogs, and the only way to _avoid_  them from a non-elevated process is to disable (parts of) UAC altogether, _which is strongly discouraged_ for security reasons. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50555081/45375) for details. I've also updated the answer with this information.

Comment: @DannyColeiro, I've found a .NET API method that doesn't require elevation and therefore presents no UAC dialog - please see my update.

Comment: If vba module starts with `Option Explicit` then `Variable not defined` error occured.

Comment: @DannyColeiro, simply add `Dim exitCode as Integer` at the top. I've updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: Glad to hear it helped, @DannyColeiro; you have a nice day too.